# Unresolved Class 'FileProvider' in manifest.xml (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I am building my first Java application. Its functionality includes taking camera images and saving them along with saving 'Project' information locally for said images to be associated with.

I believe I need to include the FileProvider to my code:

```xml
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="devkit.blade.vuzix.com.blade_template_app"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_path"></meta-data>
        </provider>
```

In the above XML .FileProvider is not resolving and so I cant build the app. What's the problem here?

Also for context @xml/provider_path references this file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to my build.grade (app module) allowed it to be referenced correctly. If you are required to use API level 27 (pre androidX) this is the way!

```xml
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I believe I need to include the FileProvider to my code

In your `<provider>` element in your manifest, try changing `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider` (the fully-qualified class name to an old edition of `FileProvider`) to [`androidx.core.content.FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider).

Comment: I tried this approach before but it says androidx is an unresolved package?? Normally android studio links packages for me so not sure...

Comment: @MichaelPaccione: Then you are missing a dependency. You need `androidx.core:core`, such as `implementation "androidx.core:core:1.5.0"`.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm REALLY new to android development as this is my first project. I'm looking at the build.gradle file and since this is for AR Glasses I can't use a very new API level. compileSDKVersion is 27... is it non breaking to add your provided implementation? I have to use the old Camera API and other things etc...

Comment: Hey working through this I had to enable androidX and then a bunch of other stuff started breaking. Can this work with the old FileProvider ... I have implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1' in the build.gradle file